# prevent autoincrementing integer primary key?

Tags: sql, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment, notnull

I have a sqlite table (sqlite version 3.7.3) where nulls inserted into the primary key column are being undesirably auto-incremented:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(bar INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES(NULL);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
1
```

In the [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint), it shows that adding the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword to the column should create this behavior, but there doesn't appear to be a keyword to **prevent** the auto incrementing...

I also found that I can build sqlite with the `SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINCREMENT` [compile option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html), but I don't want to disable the behavior **globally**, just for this particular column.

Interestingly, if I don't include the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, I get the desired behavior:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE FOO(bar integer NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO FOO(bar) VALUES(NULL);
SQL error: foo.bar may not be NULL
```

How can I define the table so that NULL values are rejected **and** keep the primary key constraint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) behavior applies only to columns declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.  So the easiest ways to disable it are:

- Declare the column as `UNIQUE` instead of `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Declare the column type as `INT` instead of `INTEGER`.

Note that either one will give you a column with integer *affinity* instead of being constrained to contain only integers.

Comment: You probably also want to combine the UNIQUE with NOT NULL to prevent creation of "idless" records in your table.

Answer (score -2):

One way to disable autoincrement (outside of recreating the table) when you need to insert data is to use the import tool in sqlite3:

If you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [table1] ( [ID] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, [col1] TEXT);
```

If you run the import command on it with your data file:

```
ID col1
10 abc
20 def

import myfile.txt table1
```

It will import the rows, and it will disregard the autoincrement feature.

Comment: Does not work for me at least. Tested with `sqlite3 --version
3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19 2ef4f3a5b1d1d0c4338f8243d40a2452cc1f7fe4`