# Why does SQLite Database rowid created by itself? Android

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, auto-increment

Is there a way to create a table without an AUTOINCREMENT column?

I have tried the solution from this link, but it didn't work for me.
[prevent autoincrementing integer primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053167/prevent-autoincrementing-integer-primary-key)

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "ROW_ID";                   
public static final String BOOK   = "books";    
public static final String CAR      = "cars";   
private static final String BOOK_CAR_TABLE = "BOOK_CAR_Table";
private static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ID, BOOK, CAR};

private static final String BOOK_CAR_CREATE =           
 "CREATE TABLE " + BOOK_CAR_TABLE + "("+ 
                                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + 
                                BOOK + " TEXT," + 
                                CAR + " TEXT)";
```

I understand that when I add INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, it will turn KEY_ID into an AUTOINCREMENT column.

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "ROW_ID";                   
public static final String BOOK   = "books";    
public static final String CAR      = "cars";   
private static final String BOOK_CAR_TABLE = "BOOK_CAR_Table";
private static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ID, BOOK, CAR};

private static final String BOOK_CAR_CREATE =           
 "CREATE TABLE " + BOOK_CAR_TABLE + "("+ 
                                KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + 
                                BOOK + " TEXT," + 
                                CAR + " TEXT)";
```

the AUTOINCREMENT rowid column was created by itself, how did it happen ?????

I don't want this AUTOINCREMENT column.

How can I prevent this?

Thank you

Edit: added code

```
private static final String BOOK_CAR_CREATE =           
 "CREATE TABLE " + BOOK_CAR_TABLE + "("+ 
                                KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + 
                                BOOK + " TEXT," + 
                                CAR + " TEXT) WITHOUT ROWID";
```

I've tried this and it was force close.  I guess it's because of the the SQLite version?

Comment: this is a feature, not a bug

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `WITHOUT ROWID` but you will still need a `PRIMARY KEY`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "table"("key" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "value" TEXT) WITHOUT ROWID
```

This requires sqlite 3.8.2 or newer. The question is tagged also with [android-sqlite](/questions/tagged/android-sqlite) so it's possible [the sqlite version on your Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) is older.

Further reading: http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html

Comment: In another words, it has to have the AUTOINCREMENT column?  Thanks

Comment: It has to have a `PRIMARY KEY` but the it doesn't really have to be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: I have updated my question.  I've tried with "WITHOUT ROWID" but it was force close. It's probably because of the SQLite version.  Thanks