# How to stop my primary key ID from incrementing?

Tags: python, sql

**Shortened, essential code, for reference:**

```
def sqlInput(groupValues, userLogin):
    sqliteConnection = None
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('NEA.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print()
        print("Connected to SQLite server.")
        print()
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Food Tracker" (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        "Entry Number" INTEGER,
                        "Calories" INTEGER,
                        "Food Item" TEXT,
                        "Date" TEXT,
                        "Time" TEXT
                    )''')

        insertQuery ="""INSERT INTO Food Tracker(
                                    "ID", "Food Item", "Calories", "Date", Time) 
                                VALUES 
                                (?,?,?,?,?,?)"""
        inserting = list(
                zip(userLogin.primarykey, groupValues.entry, groupValues.food, map(int, groupValues.calories), groupValues.date, groupValues.time))
        cursor.executemany(insertQuery,inserting)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Successfully entered data into SQLite database.")
        print()
        menu(userLogin)
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print()
        print("Failed to insert data into SQLite database:", error)
        print()
    finally:
        if sqliteConnection:
            sqliteConnection.close()
```

Here I am struggling with the lines;

```
 insertQuery ="""INSERT INTO Food Tracker(
                                    ID, Food Item, Calories, Date, Time) 
                                VALUES 
                                (?,?,?,?,?)"""
        inserting = list(
                zip(userLogin.primarykey, groupValues.entry, groupValues.food, map(int, groupValues.calories), groupValues.date, groupValues.time))
```

Everything inserts fine into the database. No problems with anything apart from the ID column. It won't display as my ID, which is stored in `userInput.primarykey` (no errors with that either), and instead of ID being "62381" for example which is a valid example ID, it will display as "1" and increment with every entry added.
**How do I get my ID to stay as 62381 for example within userInput.primarykey and not increment?**

I've tried adding a seperate foreign key, I've tried changing the order of parenthesis and using other commands such as MAP & ZIP.

Nothing works, AI won't provide an answer, I really need a solution.
Any further information needed, let me know although I believe I've added everything you'd need.

Please help me solve this, as I've had many shut down questions, but this is valid, and I need a solution, fast.

Error message: Failed to retrieve last entry number: UNIQUE constraint failed: Food Tracker.ID
How can I use the primary key multiple times?

Comment: Can you share some data and show us the full behaviour vs the expected behaviour. In other words, share `groupValues` and `userLogin` (without sensitive data if it has any) and how the table should look afterwards? Sounds like you're inserting data using the same primary key multiple times?

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code?  Your SQL insert statement has a table name `Food Tracker` and a column name `Food Item` that have embedded spaces, but they aren't quoted in the sql.  Surely that is an error.

Comment: Code is fixed, it should be accurate now.

Comment: What is "Entry Number" meant to be? I notice you're not setting it.

Comment: Are you passing 5 or 6 parameters? You have 5  columns, and pass 6 parameters and sometimes have 5 placeholders and sometimes 6....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use the primary key multiple times?

You can't. [A primary key must be unique](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP).

> How do I get my ID to stay as 62381 for example within userInput.primarykey and not increment?

Don't. Leave the ID as is and do not insert your own. [`integer primary key`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is special in SQLite and will provide a good unique primary key by default. Other databases would require you to declare it auto-increment or identity.

Instead, add another column to store `userLogin.primarykey`.

I can only guess that `userLogin.primarykey` is the ID of the user associated with that Food Tracker row. It should be "User ID" and declared as a [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_foreign_key.asp) referencing your Users table.

```
create table "Food Tracker" (
  id integer primary key,

  "User ID" integer not null references Users(id),

  -- I notice you're not using this in your insert.
  -- What is it?
  "Entry Number" integer,
  
  "Calories" integer,
  "Food Item" text not null,

  "Date" text,
  "Time" text
)
```

This assumes you have a Users table to refer to and that each `userLogin.primarykey` has an entry. You may need to insert the users before you insert their food tracker info.

---

Note1: your insert has 5 values, but you're passing in 6.

Note2: Be careful with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. If you change your table definition **it will do nothing**; you will be using the old definition. Instead, for a little test database like this, drop the table and recreate it.

Note3: Column names with spaces in them is asking for trouble, spaces are used to separate words. The result is you have to quote everything, which has its own problems, for example your `insert` forgets the quotes. In addition, most databases ignore case so `thing` and `Thing` refer to the same thing, but `"Thing"` might only refer to `Thing` and not `thing`. Consider using [thisStyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) or [this_style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Note4: Store date and time in a single column, "Tracked At". This takes less storage and makes working with the data much, much, much easier. Importing data is when you should fix these issues, combine the date & time before inserting. Also get used to using the appropriate type, [`datetime`](https://www.sqltutorial.net/datetime.html) or `timestamp` (SQLite's loose handling of types is unusual).

Comment: Could you give me an example on what column I could add alongside would it be Primary Key or no? How would it look in code, as I've been trying for HOURS. THANK YOU!!

Comment: @JushGorania I can only guess that `userLogin.primarykey` is the ID of the user associated with that row. It should be "User ID" and declared as a [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_foreign_key.asp) referencing your users table.

Comment: If it isn't too much hassle may you sketch a few lines as to how that looks? I really don't want to ask AI and have it botch my entire code and I'm still so new to this topic I really need help.

Comment: @JushGorania I'd suggest the [W3Schools Tutorial on Foreign Keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) and the [SQL Tutorial one](https://www.sqltutorial.net/foreign-key-constraint.html) to get started. For more I suggest (no joke) [The Manga Guide To Databases](https://nostarch.com/mg_databases.htm). I would recommend getting the SQL right in the [SQLite console](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), then coding it in Python.

Comment: @JushGorania I added a bit more to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

It appears what you're talking about is an auto-incrementing primary key. This is a common database feature that's typically used in scenarios where there is no intention of setting an explicit value for the primary key.

We can see in this line of DDL that you have implicitly defined the column `FoodTracker.ID` as having an auto-incrementing primary key.

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905859/is-there-auto-increment-in-sqlite) for an explanation of that behaviour.

We can see from your attempt to insert a value, passed as the first `?` parameter in this SQL, that you are attempting to explicitly set a particular value for this field.

```
INSERT INTO Food Tracker(
                                    ID, Food Item, Calories, Date, Time) 
                                VALUES 
                                (?,?,?,?,?)
```

This is not going to work, however I suggest you follow the advice in the accepted answer for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053167/prevent-autoincrementing-integer-primary-key), which suggests defining applying a `UNIQUE` constraint on the id in your table definition.

It's also suggested to use the `INT` datatype in place of `INTEGER`, which is a little odd, but has been noted by @dan04 in his comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337882/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlite-integer-data-types-like-int-integer-bigi) older SO post.

The distinction between the two data types is explained by the concept of type **affinity**, which can be read about in the official [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) section 3. Basically, `INTEGER` is a "flexible" data type, which allows cross-compatibility with other fields of similar type (i.e. dynamically typed). The data type of an auto-incrementing primary key, however, needs to behave as if statically typed, hence the **type** `INT` is given, rather than the affinity `INTEGER`.

Looking under section 2 we read

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY
> KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

which appears to suggest that a column defined in this way will not be able to store a value, like the one you have been trying to insert.

In response to your comment on this post, it appears that @Schwern was right about your intentions to insert a **foreign key** reference, rather than a primary key value, as you originally described it.

In that case, while the above still holds true for primary keys, you will probably want DDL statements something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "UserLogin" (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        "UserName" TEXT
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Food Tracker" (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        "UserLoginId" INTEGER,
                        "Entry Number" INTEGER,
                        "Calories" INTEGER,
                        "Food Item" TEXT,
                        "Date" TEXT,
                        "Time" TEXT,
                        FOREIGN KEY (UserLoginId) REFERENCES UserLogin (ID)
);
```

I'm demonstrating it here in SQL to show the underlying logic, but you can implement this with appropriate parameterization in your python application, as needed.

First, make sure we have a user:

```
INSERT INTO UserLogin (
    UserName  
)
VALUES ('42123');
```

Then we add a record to the food tracker.

```
INSERT INTO "Food Tracker" (
    "UserLoginId", 
    "Entry Number"
    --,etc.
) 
SELECT
    (
        SELECT Id FROM UserLogin
        WHERE UserName = '42123'
    ) as UserLoginId,
    7 as [EntryNumber];
```

Note that the primary key of `Food Tracker` is not specified in the insert. Also note the sub-query, which allows us to reference a particular user by a freely definable string, while retaining a unique, auto-incrementing primary key in the UserLogin table. This is often useful and is a recommended table design.

Finally, we can query for the tracking information relevant to a specific user with a simple lookup:

```
SELECT
    ul.UserName,
    ft.* 
FROM "Food Tracker" ft
    INNER JOIN UserLogin ul ON ft.UserLoginId = ul.Id
WHERE ul.UserName = '42123';
```

Comment: In the long run, it's not the auto-incremeting tool I'm fussed about, It's more how can I find a way around using the primary key in multiple columns, even though that's what I want, so for example when you type 
SELECT * FROM Username;
WHERE Username = "42123";
There will be a list of entries from Food Tracker, from user 42123 from over time.

Comment: I don't think their user name is 42123. That seems like their unique ID suitable for a primary key.